# What is the point of Python Wheels?

Tags: python, package, pip

I'm a little confused as to the actual objective of Wheels. Say we have an external dependency. Why can't I just install the librar(ies) with pip's requirements.txt? Wheels will just create zip archives of the external librar(ies), correct? Why would I need to do both?

Example: Say I have to install the library *MyLib*. Running *pip install MyLib* would accomplish the same goal as storing the Wheels file in the directory, correct?

Comment: Now do this on Windows with a library with parts written in C. Or with 25 dependencies, and they all need to run `setup.py`, and do this across 20 machines. Wheels archive *what is installed*, not source code, which is faster to install and doesn't require compilation.

Comment: See the [*Usage* section](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage) in the documentation: *For lxml, an up to 3-minute “search for the newest version and compile” can become a less-than-1 second “unpack from wheel”.*